# How can I retain indentation while using file_get_content with php?

Tags: php, html, facebook, api, file-get-contents

I am using the `file_get_contents` function in php to get the contents of a site. The problem is that on the site I am grabbing information from, the information is neatly indented, yet when I retrieve the information it looses all indentation.

The code I am using is:

```
<?php
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/btaylor";
$file = file_get_contents($url);
echo "$file";
?>
```

If you go to the [original site here](https://graph.facebook.com/btaylor), you can see how the information is set up as:

```
{
   "id": "220439",
   "name": "Bret Taylor",
   "first_name": "Bret",
   "last_name": "Taylor",
   "link": "https://www.facebook.com/btaylor",
   "username": "btaylor",
   "gender": "male",
   "locale": "en_US"
}
```

yet on [my site](http://www.donjuma.com/test.php), after grabbing the information it looks like this:

```
{"id":"220439","name":"Bret Taylor","first_name":"Bret","last_name":"Taylor","link":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/btaylor","username":"btaylor","gender":"male","locale":"en_US"}
```

How can I keep the indentation?

Thanks in advance!

By the way, the link and information is from a sample page from Facebook, and not real information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents). It solely depends on the `Content-Type` of your page. The original is plain text, while your site outputs HTML.

You can either use:

```
 header("Content-Type: text/plain");
```

Or keep the HTML type but wrap your output in `pre` tags:

```
 echo "<pre>$file</pre>";
```

Since you possibly want to reuse that mirrored JSON output, I would go for the first option. (But then an `application/json` type might be more appropriate. Not sure why you want to present it with fixed formatting anyway.)

Comment: The only reason I wanted to keep the formatting is because I thought it would affect the ability to insert things in arrays.

Comment: No, you don't need that. As you would modify the data after `json_decode()`-ing into an array, then probably encode it back into JSON

Comment: @DonJuma Perhaps you're thinking of YAML, which uses correct indentation as part of its structure. JSON does not require any sort of indentation to parse correctly.