# Retaining indentation with file_get_contents

Tags: php

I'm fetching html code using the code below, it works without any problem, the only issue is the indented code isn't retained

for example the fetched code looks like:

```
    <div>
    data
</div
```

instead of

```
<div>
    data
</div>
```

php:

```
<?php

function getFile($file)
{
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        $file = file_get_contents($file);
        return $file;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I understand it isn't an "issue" but if it's possible to retain the correct indent code I'd like to, thank you.

Comment: It has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058409/how-can-i-retain-indentation-while-using-file-get-content-with-php).

Comment: @Scamtex - sorry but it hasn't, "header("Content-Type: text/plain")" changes the code to text which isn't what I'm after

Comment: The extra 4 spaces are coming from somewhere, you just need to find it.  Maybe where you output it or before.

Comment: @AbraCadaver - I've just had a quick look, your right, there's four spaces before my brackets { html } what I was hoping was the code inside the brackets would all be indented after the four spaces

Comment: It is indented 4 spaces. Not sure what you expect.

Comment: @AbraCadaver - only the first line is indented 4 spaces, every line after isn't, as shown in the example in the first post above

Comment: Why would they be indented, they aren't in the file?  It's not magic, you can't indent one line and expect all other lines to just indent themselves.

Comment: @AbraCadaver that's what I was asking about, if it was possible to indent all the { html } lines instead of just the first one

Comment: where do you call that function `getFile()` from?

Comment: You would need to read in each line and pre-pend 4 spaces or a tab to it.

Comment: Please mark one as accepted if it solved the issue.

Comment: Did you give up?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I retain indentation while using file\_get\_content with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058409/how-can-i-retain-indentation-while-using-file-get-content-with-php)

Answer (score 1):

Your current code does retain the indentation, if you want more indentation then this is just an example using your code.  You could use spaces as shown or a tab. 
 Call it with `$indent` as the number of spaces that you want to add:

```
function getFile($file, $indent=false)
{
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        if($indent) {
            $i = (str_repeat(' ', $indent);
            $file = $i . implode($i, file($file));
        } else {
            $file = file_get_contents($file);
        }
        return $file;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

An alternative would be to create an `indent()` function and then in the above just call it:

```
$file = indent(file_get_contents($file), 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a random guess: you probably have output of few spaces somewhere in your code before you output file content to the client.

To avoid that you need to clean output. You can do that inside this `getFile()` function:

```
function getFile($file)
{
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        $file = file_get_contents($file);
        ob_clean(); // <-- clean the output if any happened before
        return $file;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Or outside where you call it I guess something like:

```
...
ob_clean();
echo getFile($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a content type encoding issue. `file_get_contents` will read the file contents using the default charset as configured in `php.ini` at setting `default_charset`, which is `UTF-8` by default.

We can use [mb_detect_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) to ensure that it is the same as the default character set, if not we have the option to convert it to the detected encoding with [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php).

```php
<?php
function getFile($file) {
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        $file = file_get_contents($file);
        $detect_enc = mb_detect_encoding($file);
        if ($detect_enc != ini_get('default_charset'))
            $file = mb_convert_encoding($file, $detect_enc);
        return $file;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

nJoy!